# MS Access SQL Join Performance Improvement

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ms-access

I was hoping for some help on how I can improve the query below which is taking an abosolute age to execute.

I'm aware it's the `LEFT JOIN` that's causing the statement to run so slowly but I have no idea how else I could run the query to improve the performance and return the required results.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name, COUNT(a.AbsenceId)
FROM ((
      dbo_ds_staff AS s
      INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_staff_member AS tsm ON s.id=tsm.staff_id
    )
    INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_leader AS tl ON tsm.team_id=tl.team_id
)
LEFT JOIN ct_adt_Absence AS a ON s.id=a.StaffId
  WHERE 
     tl.staff_id=2169
     And tsm.start_date<NOW() 
     And (
        tsm.end_date>=NOW() 
        Or tsm.end_date Is Null
    ) 
    And tl.start_date<NOW()
    And (
     tl.end_date>=NOW() 
     Or tl.end_date Is Null
   )
   GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
   ORDER BY s.first_name, s.last_name;
```

If there's any further information I can give to assist, please let me know! Thanks

Comment: I suppose tables started with "dbo_" are from MSSQL, but what is the source of ct_adt_Absence table? is it possible to add an index on ct_adt_Absence.StaffId field?

Comment: @sarh Yep the dbo_ tables are linked to MSSQL. The tables prefixed ct_adt and held in the access database. Thanks

Comment: Any chance of creating a view or pass-through for MSSQL that would give you those filters? I *think* it would be quicker to LEFT JOIN the already filtered data.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to create or modify any of the data held on MSSQL and therefore can't create a view.

Comment: A pass-through query can be created in MS Access.

Comment: Thanks @Remou. I've done some research on creating a pass-through query but I haven't got administrative permissions and therefore can't create a system dsn! Can of worms...

Comment: You should not need a system DSN, an ODBC Connection string should be enough, if you have linked tables, you already have this (`db.TableDefs("SomeTable").Connection`) You can trim it down a bit.

Comment: Thanks @Remou, I've setup the pass through query using the existing connection (sorry the MS Support centre indicated that a system DSN was required). So how could I use a pass through query to create the filters and then execute the rest of the query?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50122/discussion-between-remou-and-gareth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments to the question, a pass-through query in Access might speed things up by pushing the processing of the SQL Server tables onto SQL Server itself. For example, a pass-through query named [ptqStaffList] with SQL

```sql
SELECT 
    s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
FROM
    dbo.ds_staff AS s
    INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ds_team_staff_member AS tsm 
        ON s.id=tsm.staff_id
    INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ds_team_leader AS tl 
        ON tsm.team_id=tl.team_id
WHERE tl.staff_id=2169
    AND tsm.start_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    AND (tsm.end_date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OR tsm.end_date IS NULL)
    AND tl.start_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    AND (tl.end_date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OR tl.end_date IS NULL)
```

...which looks like this in Access...

[image: ptq.png]

...returns:

```
id  first_name  last_name
--  ----------  ---------
1   Gord        Thompson
```

We can then use that in a regular SELECT query with the local Access table

```sql
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    s.first_name, 
    s.last_name, 
    COUNT(a.AbsenceId) AS AbsenceCount
FROM
    ptqStaffList AS s
    LEFT JOIN 
    ct_adt_Absence AS a 
        ON s.id=a.StaffId
   GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
   ORDER BY s.first_name, s.last_name;
```

returning

```
id  first_name  last_name  AbsenceCount
--  ----------  ---------  ------------
1   Gord        Thompson              1
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation @Gord Thompson. I really helps to have the this as I now understand theory as well! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(a.AbsenceId)
FROM
    (SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
    FROM ((dbo_ds_staff AS s
    INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_staff_member AS tsm ON s.id=tsm.staff_id)
    INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_leader AS tl ON tsm.team_id=tl.team_id)
    WHERE tl.staff_id=2169 And tsm.start_date<NOW() And (tsm.end_date>=NOW() Or tsm.end_date Is Null) And tl.start_date<NOW() And (tl.end_date>=NOW() Or tl.end_date Is Null)
    GROUP BY s.id
    ORDER BY s.first_name, s.last_name) as s
LEFT JOIN ct_adt_Absence AS a ON s.id=a.StaffId
GROUP BY s.id
```

I would select users first and then add the LEFT JOIN to count absence.

Also I don't see why you need the grouping by first_name and last_name

Comment: Thanks for your input. When I try and run the query, Access comes back with the error `Cannot group on fields selected with '*' (s).` This was the original reason for grouping by first_name and last_name as well.

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL, after some tinkering, this is working perfectly!